# show that a metric space M is connected if and only if every continuous function $\ f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ has the intermediate value theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

I have to show that a metric space $\ M $ is connected if and only if every continuous function $\ f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ has the intermediate value theorem, that is, $ \forall$ x, y $\in M$ $\operatorname {with} f (x) <f (y)$ $\text {applies} \ [f (x), f (y)] \subseteq f (M) $

I think it's more effective, to show that $M$ is not connected, equivalent to the fact that the intermediate value theorem does not hold on $M$. Does anyone know how to go about this!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896103/42969